# QR algorithm implementation for eigensystem - where is error

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues

I implemented the simplest possible program of QR algorithm, but the program gives wrong solutions, i.e. eigenvalues (diagonal elements of converged matrix `x`) and eigenvectors (columns of matrix `pq`). Either I do not understand the algorithm or I made a mistake in the program. Where is the error?

````
a = ( {
   {1.0, 2.0, 3.0},
   {2.0, 2.0, 4.0},
   {3.0, 4.0, 3.0}
  } ); 
pq = {{1., 0., 0.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}};
x = a;
For[i = 0, i < 30, i++,
 {q, r} = QRDecomposition[x];
 pq = pq.q;
 x = r.q;
 ];

x[[1]]
{-5.73802, 5.69445, -0.87472}
es=Eigensystem[a]; 

es[[1]]
{8.28822, -1.73042, -0.5578}

```
````

Comment: If the linked thread does not suit your needs, please edit your question to explain why.

Comment: The QR algorithm runs like this: {q, r} = QRDecomposition[a];
a = q.a.Transpose[q]; and then iterate. The eigenvalues appear on the diagonal of a after iteration. I can poste the code if you reopen the question.

Comment: @DanielHuber Thanks, but it is not necessary to upload the code. I figured out myself about the transposing matrix. The point is that Mathematica's QRDecomposition[a] gives transposed R instead of R, hence it must be transposed back for next iteration. The details are already written on the page pointed by the link at the top of this page.